# Worksheet protection - why is "add all boundaries" of a cell disabled?

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

Why in excel VBA protection with the following settings is "add all boundaries" of a cell disabled?
The  `AllowFormattingCells` is set to true.

[Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)

```
Public Sub ProtectAll()
' Protect all to dis-allow modifications if locked
'' UserInterfaceOnly allows VBA code to modify locked cells.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
                ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
                    ws.Protect Password:="1234", _
                               Contents:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                               AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                               AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
                               AllowFiltering:=False, AllowSorting:=False, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
                               DrawingObjects:=False, Scenarios:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
                               
         End If
    Next
End Sub

'Unprotectall to unlock cells and allow modifications
Public Sub UnprotectAll()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
        ws.Unprotect "1234"
        ws.Cells.Locked = False
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me as all the other border buttons are enabled and also via `Ctrl + 1` you can set all the borders on a protected sheet. So there is no logic to disable just *"add all boundaries"*. In my Excel also the *"More Borders"* menu is grayed out but via `Ctrl + 1` you can still get there and format any border you want. • So in my opinion clearly a bug. You could raise a support case with Mircrosoft.

Comment: Question: Why do you `ws.Cells.Locked = False`? Note that if you do that and run `ProtectAll` all cells will be unprotected still because they are not locked anymore! I recommend to remove this line `ws.Cells.Locked = False` as it is not needed to unprotect the cells `ws.Unprotect` is enough because `.Locked = True` only has an effect in protected sheets but no effect in unprotected sheets.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/he-il/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2016/worksheet-protection-vba-add-all-boundaries-of-a/9d9e8742-23e6-4435-af28-5e3561867dcb?tm=1619521301391